# Add another insertText command inside Atom init script

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

Inside Atom I am able to run a simple text-editor insert with:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'custom:react-class': ->
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()?.insertText('text to be inserted')
```

I'd like to setup another keyboard shortcut to insert a different snippet of text, but I cant seem to get it. Can I run multiple insertText in the same script file? Should these all be in the same command?

Answer (score 0):

The following can serve as a template (it's in JavaScript, but you can either translate to CoffeeScript or rename `init.coffee` to `init.js`)
atom.

```
commands.add("atom-text-editor", {
  "custom:f1": () => {
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().insertText('executing f1');
  },
  "custom:66": () => {
    atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().insertText('executing order 66');
  },
  "custom:f2": () => { 
    atom.notifications.addSuccess("Executed f2", { dismissable: true }); 
  }
});
```

The actual functions can be as complex as you like. Anything NodeJS can do, Atom can do, and NodeJS can do anything.

The commands can then be linked to a keyboard shortcut like so

```
"atom-text-editor":
  "cmd-shift-a": "custom:f1"
  "cmd-shift-b": "custom:66"
  "cmd-shift-c": "custom:f2"
```